# Javascript - Taking a global variable, modifying it in a function - THEN taking that modified result to use in another function

Tags: javascript

I'm creating the javascript for a rock-paper-scissors game. (Full link to the code below with comments to explain.)
https://jsfiddle.net/rueeazy/8b5nw2ce/15/

I'm building a RPS game that runs 5 different times and displays the winner of me v the computer after 5 rounds. Right now the game is being played in google chrome dev tools with the results being logged through the console.

```
let myScore = 0
let pcScore = 0

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
          if (computerSelection == 'Paper' && playerSelection =='paper') {
              return 'It\'s a tie!';
          } else if (computerSelection == 'Paper' && playerSelection == 'rock') {
              return 'You lose! Paper beats rock!';
         pcScore ++;
          } else if (computerSelection == 'Paper' && playerSelection == 'scissors') {
              return 'You win! Scissors beats paper!';
          myScore ++;
          } else if (computerSelection == 'Rock' && playerSelection == 'paper') {
              return 'You win! Paper beats rock!';
              myScore ++;
          } else if (computerSelection == 'Rock' && playerSelection == 'rock') {
              return 'It\'s a tie!';
          } else if (computerSelection == 'Rock' && playerSelection == 'scissors') {
              return 'You lose! Rock beats scissors!';
              pcScore ++;
          } else if (computerSelection == 'Scissors' && playerSelection == 'paper') {
              return 'You lose! Scissors beats paper!'
              pcScore ++;
          } else if (computerSelection == 'Scissors' && playerSelection == 'rock') {
              return 'You win! Rock beats scissors!'
              myScore ++;
          } else (computerSelection == 'Scissors' && playerSelection == 'scissors') 
              return 'It\'s a tie!'
          }

function winner() {
        if (myScore > pcScore) {
            return 'You Won!';
        } else if (myScore = pcScore) {
            return 'You tied!';
        } else pcScore > myScore
            return 'The computer won!'
        }
```

I am supposed to track the score via the [console.log] after each round and display the winner. And I loop this process in function game() 5 times and keep a tally of who won more rounds - and display the winner at the end. But when I call function game() in the console - it ALWAYS displays "the computer won" so I don't believe winner() is receiving the updated result of myScore/pcScore from playRound().

```
function game() {
        console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerPlay()));
        console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerPlay()));
        console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerPlay()));
        console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerPlay()));
        console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerPlay()));
        return winner()
      }
```

The part I'm having trouble with is getting the new results of pc/my score from the function playRound() to winner() so that I can display the true winner in game().

I've tried making myScore and pcScore global variables that apply to every function in hopes that they would first be effected in playRound() and then from playRound() to winner() but that didn't seem to work. So I put myScore and pcScore *inside* the playRound() function - but don't know the correct way to define myScore and pcScore inside winner() and game().

I hope this makes sense - I appreciate the help!

Comment: So... `playerSelection` is not a function call within your `game` function?

Comment: Try increment the score first then returning statement. Think about it if you have already returned from the function, how would the function increment the score.

Comment: firstly your winner function if-else statement is wrong. you are using the assignment operator in the else if the ( ) section you need to use comparison operator ==  and in else no need to write any condition in else section. else just need to be else{
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you try to increase score after returning from the function ;

```
...
else if (computerSelection == 'Paper' && playerSelection == 'rock') {
              return 'You lose! Paper beats rock!';
         pcScore ++;
          }
...
```

this should be

```
...
else if (computerSelection == 'Paper' && playerSelection == 'rock') {
         pcScore ++;
              return 'You lose! Paper beats rock!';
          }
...
```

Comment: Needless to say all returns / increases should be adjusted

Comment: thank you that seemed to do the trick! when I run game() in the console - the first round works perfectly. if i continue to call the function game() in the console, the scores from previous games() add to the total so i get inaccurate winners the next couple rounds. Is there a way i can make each game() start where both scores equal 0?

Comment: when you initialize game you need to reset score by setting them to 0